# Como inserir vários registros com 1 insert?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso inserir vários registros com um insert

Exemplo:

$ids= "1,2,3,4"

```
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO documento (id) VALUES (1)");
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO documento (id) VALUES (2)");
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO documento (id) VALUES (3)");
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO documento (id) VALUES (4)");
```

Existe algum loop que por exemplo que verifica quantos registros tenho na minha variável $ids e faça o insert várias vezes repetindo até inserir o último registro da variável $ids

Comment: A variável segue esse padrão ou pode mudar? Sempre sera 0,1,2.. ?

Comment: Sim, será sempre esse padrão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além dos links indicados nos comentários. Para o seu caso, você pode fazer assim:

```
$ids = "1,2,3,4";
$idsArray = explode(",", $ids);
$query = "INSERT INTO documento (id, data) VALUES ";
foreach($idsArray as $id){
    $query .= "($id, now()),";
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -1);
$conn->prepare($query);
```

A string `$query` ficará assim:

```
INSERT INTO documento (id) VALUES (1,2018-06-29),(2,2018-06-29),(3,2018-06-29),(4,2018-06-29)
```

Comment: Se caso eu tivesse mais uma coluna "data" onde eu pudesse pegar a hora atual now() deixado fixo também, a onde eu mudaria no seu código?

Comment: @SmokeRohden vou colocar lá. Calma ae.

Comment: @SmokeRohden está lá. Veja se funciona.

Comment: funcionou! Quebrou um galhão Obrigado por colaborar com a resposta

Comment: @SmokeRohden tranquilo. Eu já passei por isso também! =) Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Deixo uma alternativa.

Você pode utilizar a função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) para iterar o array e aplicar uma função para cada elemento. A função por sua ver, irá executar seu papel:

```
array_map(function($id) { return "($id, now())"; }, explode(",", $ids))
```

A função [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) irá retornar um array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => (1, now())
  [1] => (2, now())
  [2] => (3, now())
  [3] => (4, now())
)
```

depois, basta juntar os elementos utilizando a função [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) separando-os pela virgula:

```
implode(', ', array_map(function($id) { return "($id, now())"; }, explode(",", $ids)))
```

#### Código completo:

```
$ids = "1,2,3,4";
$query = "INSERT INTO documento (id, data) VALUES " . implode(', ', array_map(function($id) { return "($id, now())"; }, explode(",", $ids)));
$conn->prepare($query);
```

saída da `$query` montada:

```
INSERT INTO documento (id, data) VALUES (1, now()), (2, now()), (3, now()), (4, now())
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/pt-stackoverflow-310954)

#### Referências:

- [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)
- [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)